# PrestaShop: How to add products through web services

Tags: php, web-services, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I want to add product using prestashop web services. I find multiple API's http://url_to_prestashop/api/products?schema=blank , 
http://url_to_prestashop/api/products .

Please help me with adding products using prestashop web services.

Comment: You can find the official documentation [here](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Using+the+PrestaShop+Web+Service). And the library [here](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop-webservice-lib). Have a good job :)

Comment: but i can't see how to add

Comment: Sorry, [here](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Web+service+tutorial) the tutorial. You may also see the examples in the GitHub library

Answer (score 0):

You can find the official documentation [here](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Using+the+PrestaShop+Web+Service), the official library that you can use is located [here](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop-webservice-lib) (inside you find the examples).

[Here](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Web+service+tutorial) the tutorial to add, delete, etc.

In your case follow this [link](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop-webservice-lib/blob/master/examples/Create.php) to create new data.